# SQLException: The connection string contains a badly formed name or value

Tags: java, sql-server, automated-tests

I tried to connect to MS SQL Server staging environment but it displays

```
SQLException: The connection string contains a badly formed name or value
```

Where, my password contains `{` and `}`

**How to correctly escape the characters?** 
My JDBC URL:

`jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=WHOPQDTB_test;integratedSecurity=false;user=WHOPQDTB_user;password='ahsdgahgsd';`

I try login with different password and it says Exception:

> Login failed for user 'WHOPQDTB_user'.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the actual URL you tried?  If you don't want to show us the real password, then give us a proxy we can work with.  What you showed now should fail, but not due to the JDBC URL.

Comment: This might get ugly.  You might have to change the escape characters from brackets to something else.

Comment: I cannot request another user or password for this. This is a lengthy process. I search online how to escape the character but found no solution. Any ideas bro?

Comment: This is the problem.  To escape you can use `{blah blah blah}`.  But, I don't know how/if this would work if the password itself contains `{` or `}`.  My advice is to tell your users not to create such passwords.

Comment: Yes, the password itself contains { and } in specific index. Any other advice?

Comment: in odbc you can escape `}` by adding additional `}` behind that. for example `password={abc;}}45}` would you please test if this works in jdbc too and let me know?

Comment: also you should wrap whole password with outer braces

Comment: I"m using MS SQL server. Any comments? My password contains { and }.

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft Docs - Building the Connection URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017#escaping-values-in-the-connection-url)

**Escaping Values in the Connection URL**

> You might have to escape certain parts of the connection URL values because of the inclusion of special characters such as spaces, semicolons, and quotation marks. The JDBC driver supports escaping these characters if they are enclosed in braces. For example, {;} escapes a semicolon.
>
> Escaped values can contain special characters (especially '=', ';', '[]', and space) but **cannot contain braces**. Values that must be escaped and contain braces should be added to a properties collection.

So change password or save the user/password as seperate variables and add it on Connection.

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\sqlexpress";
String user = "sa";
String pass = "secret";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
```

Here you will find the Propertie Names if you want to use a properties collection:

[Microsoft Docs - Setting the Connection Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-2017)

[java2s - Create Connection With Properties](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/CreateConnectionWithProperties.htm) has a nice example for java. It is for a MySQL Server but you only have to change the propertie names. (from the linked Page above)

**tl;dr**
*Dive in the Source*

[SourceCode - DriverManager.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/sql/DriverManager.java)

the use of `.getConnection(String url, String user, String password)` will create a `Properties` entry.

```java
@CallerSensitive
public static Connection getConnection(String url,
    String user, String password) throws SQLException {
    java.util.Properties info = new java.util.Properties();

    if (user != null) {
        info.put("user", user);
    }
    if (password != null) {
        info.put("password", password);
    }

    return (getConnection(url, info, Reflection.getCallerClass()));
}
```

*The mssql-jdbc Code*

[MSSQL-JDBC - SQLServerDriver.java](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver.java)

`public java.sql.Connection connect(String Url, Properties suppliedProperties)`
uses:

```
// Merge connectProperties (from URL) and supplied properties from user.
Properties connectProperties = parseAndMergeProperties(Url, suppliedProperties);
```

to get (extra) Properties from the given connectionUrl:

`private Properties parseAndMergeProperties(String Url, Properties suppliedProperties)`

is using:

```
Properties connectProperties = Util.parseUrl(Url, drLogger);
```

And in [MSSQL- Util.java](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/Util.java)
are the dealbreaker.

```
    if (ch == ';') {...}
case inEscapedValueStart: 
    if (ch == '}') {...}
case inEscapedValueEnd: 
    if (ch == ';') {...}
```

The **only way to bypass** this Case-switch and get straight to "SQLServerConnection.java", is to deliver a **proper Property Collection**!

[MSSQL-JDBC - SQLServerConnection.java](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java)

Function `Connection connect(Properties propsIn, SQLServerPooledConnection pooledConnection)`
respectively `Connection connectInternal(Properties propsIn, SQLServerPooledConnection pooledConnection)`:

```
sPropKey = SQLServerDriverStringProperty.PASSWORD.toString();
sPropValue = activeConnectionProperties.getProperty(sPropKey);
if (sPropValue == null) {
    sPropValue = SQLServerDriverStringProperty.PASSWORD.getDefaultValue();
    activeConnectionProperties.setProperty(sPropKey, sPropValue);
}
```

Comment: Yes he cannot escape the password in the Connection String. But he can use it as a property. (Like the MS said: "Values that must be escaped and contain braces should be added to a properties collection.")

Comment: Yes, it works by using properties but this is raw JDBC library. I need to use some other library that offer this kind of capabilities. Please suggest a good JDBC library like ormlite, jooq or something else.

Comment: JDBC is the Connection between your Java Application and your Database. jooq or ormlite are using JDBC in background. [JOOG - getting started](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual-single-page/#jooq-in-7-steps-step4)

Comment: Does Spring JDBC Template offer properties capability?

Comment: Look here [Spring io - Data Access with JDBC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc)

Comment: Thanks Cater. You are the superhero.

Comment: The current version of Util.java allows to escape `}` in the password by writing `}}`. Therefore, a password of `My{Pwd}WithBraces` becomes `{My{Pwd}}WithBraces}`.