# Hibernate connection string do MS SQL Server 2008 database name with braces

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-server-2008, java-8, connection-string

I have to connect to the database, which has braces - `{` and `}` in the name (who could do that?!).
So the database name is like `Production{guid-part-123123-123123-abcd}` and I got errors when I try to connent it.

Connection string is:

```
public synchronized static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(String dbName) {

        String url = String.format("jdbc:sqlserver://someServer:1433;databaseName=%s", dbName); // what can I do to give proper database name?

        return new Configuration().configure()
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
            .setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", "dbo")
            .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "admin")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "admin")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", url)
            .buildSessionFactory();
    }
```

How to build right url/connection string? Connection to the other databases on this server works, but if database name contains '{}' it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've managed to solve this problem, it's very simple but it took days to figure it out. Check this:

```
public synchronized static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(String dbName) {

    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://someServer:1433"; // we should skip here database name

    return new Configuration().configure()
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
        .setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", "dbo")
        .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "admin")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "admin")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", url) // url is parsed by DriverManager class
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.databaseName", dbName) // this property is not parsed but just used
        .buildSessionFactory();
}
```

As you can see, to solve it you need to pass the `dbName` as property and that means is not parsed. To find a solution helped me this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53704163/1679995